# Alert of Facebook Login Review

Tags: facebook, web-applications, facebook-apps

I understand that facebook login review is required for all apps which are developed before 30 Apr 2014. I have checked and modified my app so there should be no permission is needed to submit, I can't even see any suggested items for submission at my admin developer dashboard (https://developers.facebook.com/apps/upgrade/)

But i still see following alert today

[image]

Is it normal? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Review is NOT required for "all Apps". You only need to go through that process for additional permissions, as you can read in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login

If you still see the error while you don´t ask for permissions, just ignore it. Users will not see it anyway, only Admins/Developers/Testers of the App.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. Just wanna know if Facebook lists required permissions on my webapp developer dashboard, like user_like, manage_page etc.? Panic to see the alert ...

Comment: if you did not get them approved, you can only use user_likes and manage_pages as user with a role in the app